# Complex differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

The given question is very simple. I am simply told to draw phase portraits of vector field $z'=iz$.
However, I am having a very hard time to just picture this in my head. I am not quite getting it and would like help on how would I approach to draw this.

I know that if we have $z=x+yi$, the matrix representation of $iz$ would be $\begin{bmatrix}-y & x\\-x & -y\end{bmatrix}$

I wonder if this matrix has anything to do with this question. Help would be appreciated it. Thanks.

Comment: The matrix representation should be $$\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot y}=\pmatrix{-y\\x}=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}\pmatrix{x\\y},$$ how did you get your matrix?

Comment: I was supposed to give a 2x2 matrix from $z$ to $iz$ and $iz$ would be $-y+xi$ which would result in that 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand you can say

for any constant $k,z' = kz$ implies $z = e^{kt}$

and $i$ is just a constant.

$z = z_0 e^{it}\\
z_0 = \rho e^{i\theta}\\
z = \rho e^{i(\theta + t)}$

[image]

If you want to use matrix notation.

$z = x+iy = \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}$

$z'= iz = ix - y = \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}z$

But then you still have:

$z = e^{\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}t}z_0$

Now you plug $\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}t$ into the Taylor series:

$e^{At} = \sum \frac {(At)^n}{n!}$

$A^2 = -I\\
A^3 = -A\\
A^4 = I$

$e^{At} = \sum \frac {(-1)^nIt^{2n}}{2n!} + \frac {(-1)^nAt^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$